# how to insert one product to many categoies laravel attach()

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I have tried much time but failed.
Ex: I want result like if I insert a Product into the database and select multiple categories and store them different table then show me error like this:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'space.category_product' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `category_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`) values (1, ))
```

If I rename database table From category_products To category_product manually the show me a new Error here below :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `category_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`) values (1, ))
```

Here is my Database Code

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('model');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('availability');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->longText('images');
            $table->text('short_detail');
            $table->text('feature');
            $table->longText('purchase_delivery');
            $table->longText('replace_policy');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('category_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here is My Models:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function Products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
class Product extends Model
{
    public function Categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

ProductController:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')){
            foreach ($request->file as $file) {
                $fileExt = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $uniqId = uniqid('img-');
                $fileName[] =$uniqId.'.'.$fileExt;
                $Name = $uniqId.'.'.$fileExt;
                $file->move('public/uploads',$Name);
            }
            $images = implode(",",$fileName);
            $product = new Product();
            $product->Categories()->attach($request->categories_id);
            $product->name= $request->input('name');
            $product->model= $request->input('model');
            $product->slug= $request->input('slug');
            $product->availability= $request->input('availability');
            $product->price= $request->input('price');
            $product->images= $images;
            $product->short_detail= $request->input('short_detail');
            $product->feature= $request->input('feature');
            $product->purchase_delivery= $request->input('purchase_delivery');
            $product->replace_policy= $request->input('replace_policy');
            if ($product->save()) {
                return redirect()->route('product.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Product Added successfully');
            }
            return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error Adding New Product');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use your models

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function Products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'category_products');
    }
}
class Product extends Model
{
    public function Categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_products);
    }
}
```

Here `category_products` is a pivot table.

> Now Save

```
$product = Product::create(['name' => 'product1']);
$product->Categories()->sync([1, 3, 4]);
```

**OR**

```
$product->Categories()->attach([1, 3, 4]);
```

**Difference**

> **Sync:** You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the
> intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be
> removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is
> complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the
> intermediate table:
>
> **Attach:** It is same like append, it append the new values with the existing one

Comment: what is `[1, 3, 4]`   ?

Comment: these are categories ids

Comment: i want store for two column `$product->Categories()->attach(category_id,product_id);`

Comment: i want `$product->Categories()->sync(category_id,product_id);`

Comment: yes, it automatically get the product_id. `$product->Categories()->attach([category_id])`

Comment: `$request->categories_id` is an array of category ids ?

Comment: @UzzalHosen you don't need to pass `product_id` , just do it like this `$product->Categories()->sync([$request->categories_id]);

Comment: ` $ck=$product->save();
            $product->Categories()->attach([$request->category_id])` Not Workin

Comment: say `Column 'product_id' cannot be null`

Comment: can you try $product = Product::create([]); ?  `create` return model instance

Comment: working now i saved product after saving categories now i placed it before saving product

Comment: `$ck=$product->save();
            $product->Categories()->attach($request->input('categories_id'))`

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

```
  Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

You have typo in the name it should be `category_product`.

Your table name should be alphabetically ordered and use singular names.

If you do not want to change the table names

```
 public function Categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_products,'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

My ProductController :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')){
            foreach ($request->file as $file) {
                $fileExt = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $uniqId = uniqid('img-');
                $fileName[] =$uniqId.'.'.$fileExt;
                $Name = $uniqId.'.'.$fileExt;
                $file->move('public/uploads',$Name);
            }
            $images = implode(",",$fileName);
            $product = new Product();
            $product->name= $request->input('name');
            $product->model= $request->input('model');
            $product->slug= $request->input('slug');
            $product->availability= $request->input('availability');
            $product->price= $request->input('price');
            $product->images= $images;
            $product->short_detail= $request->input('short_detail');
            $product->feature= $request->input('feature');
            $product->purchase_delivery= $request->input('purchase_delivery');
            $product->replace_policy= $request->input('replace_policy');

            $product->save();
            $product->Categories()->attach($request->categories_id);

            if ($product->save()) {
                return redirect()->route('product.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Product Added successfully');
            }
            return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error Adding New Product');
        }
    }
```

Use `$product->categories()->attach($category_id)` after the `$product->save()`

Comment: did it but it show me like this SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `category_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`) values (1, ))

Comment: @UzzalHosen post the code where you are trying to use ```attach```

Comment: here is my code `$product->Categories()->attach($request->categories_id)`

Comment: `$product = new Product();
            $product->Categories()->attach($request->categories_id);`

Comment: @UzzalHosen use $attach after the $product->save() because at that time product is not created.

Comment: now this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `category_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`) values (1, ))`

Comment: @UzzalHosen have you used the code that i have pasted above?

Comment: yes i used in if condition `if ($product->save()) {
                $product->Categories()->attach($request->categories_id);
                return redirect()->route('product.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Product Added successfully');
            }`